# Why is my Deployment script causing me errors?

Tags: sql, database, visual-studio, stored-procedures, deployment

I am working on a project in visual studio 2012. Recently, I added a database project to the solution. The database already existed before I added it to the solution and everything worked fine. 
Now, however, when I try to run the application I get errors. The errors are being caused by a computer-generated file called [database name].sql. At the top of the tile, it reads:

```
/*
Deployment script for [the database name here]

This code was generated by a tool.
Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
the code is regenerated.
*/
```

This file gets re-created every time the application runs. The errors that occur appear to be syntax errors. I cannot fix them because any changes I make to the file are irrelevant because a new file gets generated with each run and the errors re-appear.

I tried looking into this more online but had trouble. This is all rather new to me.

Here are some of the errors being created:

```
GO
:setvar DatabaseName "(the database name is here)"
```

which gives me three errors that read:

```
Error   88  SQL80001: Incorrect syntax near ':'.    
Error   89  SQL80001: 'DatabaseName' is not a recognized option.
Error   90  SQL80001: Incorrect syntax near '"(the database name is here in the code)"'.
```

Also, there is a line of code that reads:

```
CREATE USER [(the domain)\(the username)] FOR LOGIN [(the domain)\(the username)];


GO
```

which gives the following error:

```
Error   119 SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 15401, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Windows NT user or group '(the domain)\(the username)' not found. Check the name again.
```

Comment: Perhaps including the actual errors might help. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What are the errors? Even though the code generating the errors can't be changed directly, there's going to be another way to make sure that the generated code is correct.

Comment: update: included errors

Answer (score 0):

From the errors you have posted it looks like there are two issues:

1. `Windows NT user or group '(the domain)\(the username)' not found.` - The user being used to access the database doesn't exist. As it's a Windows user I'm guessing that it uses the current user's credentials.

   Make sure that your instance of SQL can accept Windows logins and that you (and anyone else building the software) has the necessary access rights.
2. `'DatabaseName' is not a recognized option.` - This is more than likely also caused by the first issue, but double check that the database exists.

Answer (score 0):

The error message caught me out recently as it did not relate to the cause of my problem at all. It turns out my SQL script was incorrectly written (for my case - I forgot to add IDENTITY (1,1) to my PK column) to begin with.

Moral of the story for me was to test out the SQL data file in SSMS first.